# Put multiple parameters to ContentResolver.requestSync

Tags: android, serialization, android-intent, android-contentresolver, android-syncadapter

i'm making an app that has a syncAdapter.

i wish to be able to do a requestSync together with some parameters that will be sent via its bundle . the reason is that i wish to choose what the syncAdapter instance would do .

for some reason , both putSerializable and putIntArray causes the ContentResolver to throw an exception :

```
08-16 14:34:49.080: E/AndroidRuntime(10318): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unexpected value type: java.util.MiniEnumSet
08-16 14:34:49.080: E/AndroidRuntime(10318):    at android.content.ContentResolver.validateSyncExtrasBundle(ContentResolver.java:1144)
08-16 14:34:49.080: E/AndroidRuntime(10318):    at android.content.ContentResolver.requestSync(ContentResolver.java:1111)
08-16 14:34:49.080: E/AndroidRuntime(10318):    at com.sciatis.syncer.syncing.SyncAdapter.requestSync(SyncAdapter.java:100)
08-16 14:34:49.080: E/AndroidRuntime(10318):    at 
...
```

why does it happen? is there a way to overcome this ? putting an integer worked fine yet those operations didn't.

am i doing something wrong ? is there a better way to achieve sending parameters to the syncAdapter from an activity ?

Comment: from doc: `Only values of the following types may be used in the extras bundle: 
Integer, 
Long, 
Boolean, 
Float, 
Double, 
String` ... put something like `arrc` with array length and then `arr0` to `arrn` where `n` = `arrc` - 1

Comment: can you please put the link of the docs? also , please put your answer in a post so that i can vote for it , and please explain more about your suggestion...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ContentResolver.requestSync](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#requestSync(android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle))  says:

> Only values of the following types may be used in the extras bundle:
> Integer
> Long
> Boolean
> Float
> Double
> String

in that case you could try:

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle(); 
int[] arr = new int[] {1,2,3,4};
extras.putInt("arrlen", arr.length);
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
  extras.putInt("arr"+ i, arr[i]);
}
```

and then read those values in SyncAdapter:

```
Bundle extras; //taken from method params
int[] arr = new int[extras.getInt("arrlen")];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
  arr[i] = extras.getInt("arr"+ i);
}
```

Comment: oh now i understand . thanks . in my case , i wanted to pass an enumSet , so till you wrote the solution i've used a string separated by "," . i think your solution would still work for it too , right?

Comment: yeah, but yours shuold be good, too ... and i think that yours solution consume less memory than mine :)

Comment: you think? ok , i will use mine , though your solution is quite good too.